# How does "Link to Documentation" work?

Tags: support

The options in the Link menu look like this:

[image: Insert Link to Documentation requires a Tag and Keywords]

It looks like it will just insert a link to search the documentation; is that true? I want to link to a specific example.

Regardless of what it does, is there any specific reason to use this method instead of using the "share" link directly from the example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you fill out the `Tag` and `Keywords` fields, you are presented with a list of possible examples to select.

[image: Possible Examples]

From here, you can select an example and press 'OK'

[image: Select Example and Press OK]

The appropriate markdown is added to the post to link to the example you've selected.

[image: Generated markdown]